# "This app isn't working refresh your browser or try again later"

Tags: office365, powerapps

I am having an issue in Power Apps where literally only one user is having this error appear when trying to log in to an app.

For this user it does not matter which computer they use, the same error appears. Other users are able to log in to the same computer and use the app without issues. Using a different browser likewise makes no difference.

The only abnormal thing I have been able to find is that under the connections for an app, the Office 365 Outlook connection does not seem to be appearing under the app as it should. It can be seen under the users' connections, but does not show as being used by the app itself.

I have looked around, but cannot find any issues dealing with a connection not appearing for one specific user within an app. I have no idea what would have lead to this situation.

We have tried clearing the cache, deleting connections, removing and re-adding the user, trying past versions of the app, nothing seems to be working.

Any advice on ways to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the session id (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/get-sessionid) for the user that is having the problem...

Comment: Session ID was: 81bd7ff6-03ad-4a2c-9e2b-2a9670f1e215

Comment: It seems like there was a bug that was fixed on Thursday/Friday (depending on the time zone) that would cause that (it was the cause of the issue on this session id). Hopefully if the user retries it should work

Comment: Thank you for the response Carlos, seems to be working now!